# How to select from mysql tables randomly or shuffle it?

Tags: php, html, mysql, random

I am working on a quiz app

1. image 1 shows the index.php page
2. image 2 shows the first question
3. image 3 shows the second question
4. image 4 shows the third question
5. image 5 shows the result after completing the quiz
6. image 6 shows the database 'quizzer' and its tables
7. image 7 shows the 'questions' table
8. image 8 shows the 'choices' table

THIS LINK CONTAIN ALL THE CODE (and images) I HAVE DONE SO FAR

https://www.mediafire.com/folder/g5ao7f5q0fe6y/quiz

1.Now my question is how to select the question RANDOMLY from 'questions' table
along with 'choices' (**by adding code to the existing file or create a new one**).

2.If user refresh/reload the page before starting ('Start Quiz') or click 'Take Again' after finishing the quiz,
the question should appear randomly.

3.**Basically I want to change the order of question appearing in the browser each time I refresh.**

4.My work so far is mentioned above.........**Please help me with this "RANDOM" problem** !!

**P.S** - Will it be possible, by creating a random function in PHP which will check for repeat questions in a session and
check for the 'id' of the question and if it is new display it on the page.

If so what should I do and if no then how to do?

Comment: you are taking value from url `$number = (int) $_GET['n'];`
take `$number = rand(1, 3);` so that each time value will change automatically

Comment: tried that but not all questions are appearing..suppose randomly if it select question number '3' then quiz is over after answering it..if it select '2' then '3' then quiz is over after answering..moreover it is saying 'Question 2 of 3' when showing question '2'..instead it should show 'Question 1 of 3' if it select it first

Answer (score 2):

You can try **`order by RAND()`**

a RAND() is a mysql function used to get data randomly, further you can add conditions as per your need in the above sql statement.
I hope this gonna help you
keep coding

thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This is not a fully-qualified answer, but try playing with adding `ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1` to your SQL-query. That's basically the way to retrieve a random entry from a table in MySQL. From there on, you could use the ID to pick out the answer from that table.

Answer (score 0):

I understood that you want to select a question randomly and you don't want to select the same question in one session( is this right? ).
I suggest to create question-appearing-sequence and save in $_SESSION when user start quiz.

--- like this ---

```
$questions = array();
for ($i=0; $i < $total; $i++) {
    $questions[$i] = $i + 1;
}
$randomizedSequence = shuffle($questions);
$_SESSION['sequence'] = $randomizedSequence;
```

--- like this ---

And create query to select the question according to the parameter 'n' of question.php.

--- like this ---

```
$number = $_GET['n'] - 1;
$query = 'SELECT * FROM `questions`
          WHERE question_number = ' . $_SESSION['sequence'][$number];
```

--- like this ---

I hope i can help you.